# The fields in my form are not binding to the model attributes in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm learning Angular. My form is not binding the input fields to the model attributes.

I have a role-form and a Role model. I have imported to FormsModule ins the app.module.ts but still nothing. The submit form works fine, but the data in the form is not being bound to the model. I even checked the role object being submitted from the form but it shows that the model attributes are empty.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
export class Role {
    id: string;
    createdAt: Date;
    createdBy: string;
    modifiedAt: Date;
    modifiedBy: string;
    code: string;
    role: string;
    description: string;
}
```

```js
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { RoleService } from '../../service/role/role.service';
import { Role } from '../../model/role';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-role-form',
  templateUrl: './role-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./role-form.component.css']
})
export class RoleFormComponent{

  role: Role;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private roleService: RoleService) {
    this.role = new Role();
  }

  submitRole(){
    console.log(this.role);
    this.roleService.save(this.role).subscribe(result => this.gotoRoleList());
  }

  gotoRoleList(){
    this.router.navigate(['/roles']);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="card my-5">
  <div class="card-body">
    <form (ngSubmit)="submitRole()" #roleForm="ngForm">
      <div class=form-group>
          <label for="code">Name</label>
          <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="role.code"
            class="form-control" id="code" name="code" placeholder="Enter your code"
            required #code="ngModel">
        </div>
      <div [hidden]="!code.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">Name is required</div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="role">Role</label>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="role.role" 
          class="form-control" id="role" name="role" placeholder="Enter role"
          required #role="ngModel">
        <div [hidden]="!role.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">Role is required</div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="description">Description</label>
        <textarea [(ngModel)]="role.description" 
          class="form-control" id="description" name="description" placeholder="Enter description"
          cols="30" rows="10" #description="ngModel"></textarea>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" [disabled]="!roleForm.form.valid" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import { RoleListComponent } from './view/role-list/role-list.component';
import { RoleFormComponent } from './form/role-form/role-form.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'roles', component: RoleListComponent },
    { path: 'addrole', component: RoleFormComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { RoleListComponent } from './view/role-list/role-list.component';
import { RoleFormComponent } from './form/role-form/role-form.component';
import { RoleService } from './service/role/role.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    RoleListComponent,
    RoleFormComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [RoleService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: try declaring like this role: Role[] = [];

Comment: you should move the `this.role = new Role();` in the ngOnInit method, and add the `implements OnInit` on your component class

Comment: can you show us your `Role` model too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You named the role input control the same as the field inside the component:

```html
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="role.role" 
       class="form-control" id="role" name="role" placeholder="Enter role"
       required #role="ngModel">
```

Note the `#role="ngModel"`. The control name takes precedence in template, so whenever you used `role` field in the HTML template, in fact you were referring to the control itself.

To fix the issue all you need is to change `#role="ngModel"` to something like `#roleControl="ngModel"`. Also don't forget to update the field validation:

```html
<div [hidden]="!roleControl.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">Role is required</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved me. :)